# MongoDB criteria with $trim using MongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate, spring-mongodb

I'm trying to write a Java code for below MongoDB command using MongoTemplate and Criteria and Trim function on the field value in Mongo collection

```
db.employees.aggregate([
     {
        $match : {$expr: {$eq: [{ $trim: {input: "empName"}}, "John Smith"]}}
     }
])
```

I can see we have class as StringOperator in the **spring-data-mongodb** jar that contains trim() function returning an instance of Trim class but I'm unable to find a way to use it with Criteria or AggregationExpression which I could use with mongoTemplate.aggregate()

P.S. I can achieve same using **MongoCollection** by constructing a list of org.bson.Document and simply invoking a method like but I'm looking to achieve same using mongoTemplate.aggregate() itself

```
List<Document> pipelineDocumentList = constructPipelineDocument(empName);
mongoTemplate.getCollection("employees").aggregate(pipelineDocumentList, Employee.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AggregationOperation matchStage = Aggregation.match(
        EvaluationOperators.valueOf(
                Eq.valueOf(
                        Trim.valueOf("empName")
                ).equalToValue("John Smith")
        ).expr()
);

List<Employee> e = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
    Aggregation.newAggregation(matchStage),
    Employee.class,
    Employee.class
)
.getMappedResults();
```